# Python matplotlib title at wrong place

Tags: python, matplotlib

The title *pie* is not at the top of the figure.
Here is my code:

```py
data = [0.4,0.3,0.1,0.2]
labels = ['Music','Dance','Program','Math']
explode = [0, 0.2, 0, 0] 
colors=['#9999ff','#ff9999','#7777aa','#2442aa','#dd5555'] 

plt.axes(aspect='equal')
plt.pie(x=data,
        labels=labels,
        explode=explode,
        colors=colors,
        autopct='%.1f%%', 
        pctdistance=0.6,  
        labeldistance = 1.1, 
        radius = 2,
        wedgeprops = {'linewidth': 2, 'edgecolor':'pink'}, 
        textprops = {'fontsize':19 ,'color':'k'},
        center = (0.2,0.2))
plt.title('pie')
plt.show()
```

Picture by the code
[pie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLHxj.png)

Comment: Did you try `set_title()` method?

Comment: It works, I just need to adjust it manually.